# Has PPTX been updated to include secondary axes?

Tags: python, python-pptx

Someone else has asked this question, but it was from over a year ago and wanted to see if any updates had been made - does PPTX support putting a series of data on a secondary axis? Original question:

[Is it possible to set two value axis in python-pptx (one left, one right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047694/is-it-possible-to-set-two-value-axis-in-python-pptx-one-left-one-right)

Just looking to see if any progress has been made. Thanks!